# Xcode New Macbook Pro How to Add My Profile

Tags: xcode, certificate, code-signing, keychain, ios-provisioning

I just got a new Macbook Pro to work on my code, and I'm trying to get my code signing setup on it.  I am trying to follow Apple's directions, but have just gotten lost.

From what I understand, I went on my iMac, Organizer, Devices, and clicked on my team. I then exported it to my desktop. However when to go in Xcode on my MBP in the same spot, no team shows up for me to import this profile package. Am I completely lost?

Moreless my question is, how do I setup a new Mac to work with my existing developer profile?

Comment: You should just be able to double-click the .devprofile that got exported from Finder to start the import. Does that not work?

Comment: yeah it definitely would have, my issue was that i thought i had downloaded the two certificates (developer and distribution) and installed them my keychain, but i didn't.  This in turn did not let teams appear in my organizer, now allowing me to import the devprofile.  Sigh, ive been too deep into code that im not thinking straight.  Thank you though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i was little pre-emptive in my strike and i apologize. For others with this issue, here was my workflow to setup xcode on a new Mac.

1- Buy New Mac
2- Login to Provisioning portal at developer.apple.com
3- Download Developer and Distribution Certificates to desktop
4- Double click each individually and ok them to be added to your keychain (i chose system)
5- This will make Teams show up in Organizer / Devices (which was my problem)
6- Then Click your team, then import, put in your password.  Done, all setup

Comment: Cool. I might suggest [migration assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4889) when you buy a new mac, all that stuff just migrated over with no headaches (plus is does all your installed programs, files, etc).

Comment: thats actually a really good idea, probably the best way!  thank u!